# How do I convert a List<object> to a JsonResult?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, jsonresult

I'm trying to take a List of objects and return them as a `JsonResult` to an AJAX call.  I'm trying this:

```
List<object> list = getList();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JsonResult json = jss.Serialize(list);
```

`jss.Serialize` takes an object as its parameter, so this is obviously not working.  Is there a way I can just pass in a List of objects and get what I need returned?

Comment: you should use [`Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx) method from controller

Comment: `jss.Serialize takes an object as it's parameter, so this is obviously not working` this statement doesn't make sense

Comment: I'm saying this is what I have but it's not working.  Meant to give a general idea of what I was going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows how to return an instance of the
`JsonResult` class from an action method. The object that is returned
specifies that a `GET` request is permitted.

```
 public ActionResult Movies()
 {
     var movies = new List<object>();

     movies.Add(new { Title = "Ghostbusters", Genre = "Comedy", Year = 1984 );
     movies.Add(new { Title = "Gone with Wind", Genre = "Drama", Year = 1939 );
     movies.Add(new { Title = "Star Wars", Genre = "Science Fiction", Year = 1977 });

     return Json(movies, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The MVC `Controller` class has a [`Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx) method which is used to convert an object into a `JsonResult`.  You do not need to manually serialize the object using `JavaScriptSerializer`.  Just pass the object to the `Json` method, and it will be serialized for you when the result is executed.  If your controller method is a `GET` method, then you will also need to pass `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as the second parameter of the `Json` method, otherwise it will throw an error.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMyList()
{
    List<object> list = getList();
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```